# require module does not respond object as singleton pattern in some cases

Tags: node.js, singleton, require

file_a.js is dependency of file_b.js and file_c.js. Please take a look in file_c.js, there is weird thing there.

file_a.js

```
module.exports = {
    test: null,
    setTest: function(a){
        this.test = a;
    },
    getTest: function(){
        return this.test
    },
}
```

file_b.js

```
var a = require('./file_a')
var b = {
   print: function(someVar){
       console.log(someVar);
   }
}
a.setTest(b)
```

file_c.js

this way will work

```
var a = require('./file_a')
console.log(typeof a.getTest().print) //function
```

this way will NOT work

```
var a = require('./file_a').getTest() 
console.log(typeof a.print)  //Cannot read property 'print' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples for `file_c.js` throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of null`.

Module from `file_b.js` sets `test` property from module `file_a.js` on its initialization, and in your snippets it never gets initialized. To fix this, you need:

```
var a = require('./file_a');
require('./file_b'); // now `test` is set
console.log(typeof a.getTest().print); // function
```

or

```
require('./file_b'); // module from `file_a` loaded to cache and `test` is set
var a = require('./file_a').getTest();
console.log(typeof a.print); // function
```